# opening .git/config : Permission denied

Tags: git, git-branch

`C:\Users\Inspiron\.git\config` folder is empty and command `$git config user.email user@gmail.com` returns error: opening  .git/config: permission denied.
I try to set post buffer size,but get same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not a folder its the main configuration file for git.

Here you can see the files for configuration

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Permission denied under windows its a bit strange. Check the permissions of the file. Perhaps you have removed the Permissions in the extended permissions.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure it's not supposed to be a folder.  Delete it and let git create it.

Comment: Mine was a folder for some reason. I deleted it and created a file and that fixed it

Answer (score 2):

**Check Windows Security Properties**

On Windows 7, I was only able to fix this by right clicking on the file in explorer, clicking properties/security tab/advanced/permissions and removing the 'deny' permission type. chmod and chown did nothing for me.

Comment: Also worked for me, thanks a lot! The problem came after I `git branch -D label` a branch

Answer (score 0):

Not only `.git/config` is a file, but its permission must soon (Git 2.0.X/2.1, Q3 2014) *not* include "world writable".

See [commit daa22c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/daa22c6f8da466bd7a438f1bc27375fd737ffcf3) by  Eric Wong

#### `config`: preserve config file permissions on edits

> Users may already store sensitive data such as `imap.pass` in `.git/config`; making the file world-readable when "`git config`" is called to edit means their password would be compromised on a shared system.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, I was only able to fix this by right clicking on the file in Explorer, enter the path of config file (`C:\ProgramData\Git`), right clicking on config file `properties/security`, tab "**advanced/permissions**" and give full access to `LogonSessionId_0_XXXXXXX (NT AUTHORITY)`.