# fatal: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied

Tags: git

Git was working fine but when I tried to push today I got an error:

> fatal: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied

I have not changed any git settings recently.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143397/opening-git-config-permission-denied) seemed to be of a similar issue, but I am not sure how to find where the `.git/config` is located. I tried running `git config --list --show-origin` but all git commands give me the same error.

How do I get git working again? If it matters, I am on Windows (no admin privileges), using Bitbucket.

Comment: What OS are you running, and have you executed any `git` commands as superuser?

Comment: I am on Windows, and do not have admin rights to this computer @merlin2011

Comment: Can you check the owner of the `.git/config` file on your local clone?

Comment: @merlin2011 it says I am the owner of the file

Comment: In that case I'd recommend checking permissions on that file. The reason all `git` commands are failing is because all `git` commands are first trying to read that file before doing anything else. Additionally, I might try rebooting your system in case the problem is that some other program has taken a lock on the file.

Comment: @merlin2011 I rebooted as well as changed permissions on the file so that I would have every permission, but I still have the same error :/

Answer (score 1):

The first test is to see if the error persists with:

- the latest Git for Windows (uncompress Git 2.13 [`PortableGit-2.13.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.13.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.13.0-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, for instance in `C:\Git2.13`)
- a simplify PATH.

In a CMD, type:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\Git2.13
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Then type '`bash`', and in the bash session, try your `git config` or `git push` commands again.