# Git convert between tabs and spaces but only sometimes

Tags: git, whitespace

First, I'm a newbie to git.  Like, I could barely tell a cache from an index if it hit me in the staging area.  Or something like that.  With that out of the way, my problem is this:

Suppose I want to work on a project whose coding style mandates spaces for indentation, but I like tabs.  It seems that I can use the clean and smudge features, but there's a catch.  The coding style is not followed consistently, and there some files that mix tabs and spaces on the same line.  Thus a naïve approach would result in me making a one line change, but accidentally creating a massive commit which brings the project into full compliance with its own standards.  This would be great except that the diffs would be less useful so I end up with new enemies.

So the question is: is there a way to get this magic working in such a way that if I don't touch a file, it stays out of the picture?  (I'm willing to take full responsibility for the whitespace of files I do touch, even if I change only a single character.)

EDIT: Okay, I just in-accepted the answer I accepted yesterday.  I'm pretty sure this is very rude of me.  My excuse is that I only got around to testing it today.  Since apparently two people misunderstood me already, let me be clear on what I actually did, so maybe someone can tell me if I'm being confused and/or confusing.

```
$ ls -a
.  ..  t.txt
$ hd t.txt # file contains 3 bytes: a tab, a capital A, and a newline
00000000  09 41 0a                                          |.A.|
00000003
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/marvy/test/.git/
$ git config --local git config --local user.name me
$ git config --local user.email me@example.com
$ git add t.txt
$ git commit
[master (root-commit) 959bf99] testing cleverness of git status
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 t.txt
$ echo '*.txt filter=tabspace' > .git/info/attributes
$ cat .git/info/attributes
*.txt filter=tabspace
$ git config --local filter.tabspace.smudge unexpand
$ git config --local filter.tabspace.clean expand
$ rm t.txt
$ git checkout t.txt
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   t.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git help --stackoverflow
```

As we can see here, git status reports that t.txt is modified, even though I just checked it out.  If you run git diff, it will claim I want to convert tabs to spaces.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No answer to your question, but I'm curious about why you're going to all this trouble. I used to strongly prefer tabs over spaces, too, when editors were rather dumb. But since IDE editors have grown syntax-awareness, I have a hard time telling the difference. What editor are you using where tabs are actually easier to edit?

Comment: try this in your favorite editor.  position the cursor at the "beginning" of a line; that is, the first non-blank character.  now press the left arrow key on your keyboard.  what happens?

Comment: Okay. I seldom or never need to do that.

Comment: Really?  I probably do this many times in any given hour, and would do it more if it actually worked properly.  I guess everyone is different :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a pre-commit hook and only loop through your edited files and replaces the tabs with spaces. Something like the below:

```
FILES=`git status -s -uno | egrep '^M' | sed 's/^M//'`

for FILE in $FILES
do
    (sed -i 's/[[:space:]]*$//' "$FILE" > /dev/null 2>&1 || sed -i '' -E 's/[[:space:]]*$//' "$FILE")
fi
```

Comment: Does this actually work?  Is "git status" clever enough to realize that files haven't changed, even though they look different on disk and in the repo?  If so, does that mean the original "naïve" solution with smudge and clean also works?  (Also: I'm on Windows, no sed for me.  Though come to think of it I do have Cygwin installed.  Hm...)

Comment: @MarkVY Is "git status" clever enough to realize that files haven't changed, even though they look different on disk and in the repo? Yes it is. Yes, smudge and clean work, and are executed as bash script, even on Windows. And yes, you have sed, and 200+ other unix command right from your CMD session (no bash or cygwin required): you just need to add usr/bin from your Git installation, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44510644/6309.

Comment: Okay, that is lovely!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it is to use script with `smudge-clean`.

## `smudge-clean`

Smudge/Clean are filters which runs wherever a file is passed through the stage area and those filters will modify the file by executing the given script.

[image]

Using smudge and clean will touch only the files you pass through the staging area.

---

For example (unix sample):
If you are unfamiliar with `uexpand/unuexpand` read about it 
[here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uexpand.htm)

#### ~/.gitconfig

```
# filters to convert between tabs to spaces
[filter "tabspace"]
    smudge = unexpand --tabs=2 --first-only
    clean = expand --tabs=2 --initial
```

#### ~/.gitattributes

```
*.txt  filter=tabspace
```

Now any time you add/checkout files they will be converted based upon your configuration.

You can also take a look on this [project in github](https://github.com/gilesbowkett/git-smudge-and-clean)

Comment: It seems I'm being hopelessly unclear, because everyone is trying to answer a question that I didn't ask.  The setup you advocate would result in git status claiming that I have modified files that I never touched, because those files do not conform to the official project coding style, and the filters would try to make them conform.  The entire point of my question was how to avoid this!  I know I said I'm a git newbie, but that doesn't mean that I'm so helpless that I can't read documentation.  Give me a little credit here :)

Comment: Enjoy your auto-bounty :)  I'm still not accepting the answer though.  It's a good answer, just not to my question :)

Answer (score 1):

**Setting up the repository:**

1. Fetch the repository.
2. Merge to your local master branch.

**Make the big change:**

3. You can change the entire repository if you like. do whatever you want and whatever you need to do. make that one line change which changes everything. But only add the files which you yourself have touched to the "staging area". In other words you'll have to manually add those files: `git add FilesYouWantToAdd.txt` and any other files you are responsible for. Don't add the files you are not responsible for to the staging area.

   git commit -m 'alter spaces to tabs'  // adding only the files you are responsible for.

   git push

and you're done.

**Discard the other changes:**

because nothing substantial in the rest of the files has changed you can simply discard those changes.

```
git reset HEAD .
```

It's actually quite simple. Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
[image: git modified]

Comment: In other words, "git status" will be of no use in identifying what I haven't changed, right?

Comment: @MarkVY if any changes are made to a file (and saved) git status will show the file as being modified see image added above.

Comment: Sure, if a file is modified, git status will show it has been modified.  But if a file has NOT been modified, then git status can STILL claim it has been modified, because the version of the file in the repo does not match the version that would be produced by the clean filter if the clean filter is run on the version in the working directory.  Right?

Comment: I define "change" as anything different happening to a file and it being saved. e.g.. if you remove a space and add a tab - if you alter just one character - and save the document this would constitute a change according to git. my understanding is thatt the clean filter is in fact MODIFYING all the files. so you would have to manually add, to the staging area, all of the files which you alone are working on - and only you would know that. if' they are all in the same folder it's easy - just add the folder to the staging area. hope this is making sense?

Comment: Yes, this is making sense, it's just not what I want.  I want some kind of magic where git makes a distinction bewtween "modified by me" and "modified by the filters I have set up".

Comment: might be easier just to create a text file which you can keep repasting into the command line with all the files you need to add: e.g. git add file1.txt file2.txt etc that's probably the easiest - assuming you aren't dealing with too many.

Comment: That's sufficiently inconvenient that I'd rather live without the filters instead.  The problem is not too few vs too many.  The problem is that sometimes I myself don't remember what I've changed, and I use git status as a reminder.  But I will keep the idea in mind, it's might come in useful in some other context.