# Can VSCode shows spaces for me and tabs for a colleague?

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation, prettier, editorconfig

Our repo has indent with 2 spaces. My colleague prefers tabs. Can VSCode does a conversions to tabs while opening a file?

I've tried [EditorConfig](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig) extension for VSCode but it doesn't format a file on open. The file is opened with 2 spaces even if I have this *.editorconfig*:

```
[*]
indent_style = tabs
indent_size = 4
```

*Note: We use Prettier in pre-commit hook to format everything.*

Comment: See https://alexzaytsev.me/2014/10/19/git-filter-to-convert-spaces-to-tabs-and-vice-versa/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770689/git-convert-between-tabs-and-spaces-but-only-sometimes

Comment: @jarmod The git filter can convert indents on checkout indeed. The problem is that when I do checkout and all the files are converted from spaces to tabs and I do `git diff` I got tons of changes from all of the files.

Comment: Of course it would. The files have been modified.Spaces or tabs, Code will treat them similarly anyway.

Comment: See `git diff -b`, `git diff -w`, and optionally `--ignore-space-at-eol`.

Comment: @jarmod `git diff -b` might ignore whitespace in command line but VSCode is not able (yet) to ignore them and shows tons of changes. Therefore the solution using git filter is not suitable for my case. Thank you anyway.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40779222