# how to fix the error fatal: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied

Tags: git, flutter, dart

I'm having this error when I updated my flutter into 1.17. I'm using mac os. 
I read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506129/fatal-unable-to-access-git-config-permission-denied) but it's for windows only

when I run flutter doctor --verbose in the terminal this is the result

```
fee@Mac-mini ~ % flutter doctor --verbose
warning: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied
fatal: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied
Failed to find the latest git commit date: VersionCheckError: Command exited
with code 128: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ad
--date=iso
Standard out: 
Standard error: warning: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied
fatal: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied

Returning 1970-01-01 08:00:00.000 instead.
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, 0.0.0-unknown, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale
    en-US)
    • Flutter version 0.0.0-unknown at /Users/fee/Documents/flutter
    • Framework revision  (), 1970-01-01 08:00:00.000
    • Engine revision b59e3e9c39
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-8.0.dev 2bf3259005)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/fee/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.4.1, Build version 11E503a
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max • A3F7AF6B-81A2-44AB-9FE3-8C37668902D6 • ios
      • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-4 (simulator)
    • Web Server        • web-server                           • web-javascript
      • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome            • chrome                               • web-javascript
      • Google Chrome 81.0.4044.138

• No issues found!
```

and I run this command to reinstall the flutter but it become worse because it delete the flutter and I cannot reinstall the flutter because it says that git/config permission denied

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```

thank you for your help appreciated

Comment: check the access rights on the `.git` directory and the `.git/config` file (`ls -ld .git; ls -l .git/config` in a console, or right-click > informations from macOS finder)

Comment: sorry for the late reply my console says that no such file or directory @LeGEC

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the git config file might be worth trying. You can delete the config file by `rm .git/config`. Try with elevated permissions (sudo) if that doesn't work. After deleting the config file, run over through the [Flutter setup](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#get-sdk) again.