# how to allow the access of git/config in mac os?

Tags: git, flutter, github, dart, permissions

I having this problem because when I run flutter doctor it says . btw I'm using mac os

```
Failed to find the latest git commit date: VersionCheckError: Command exited
with code 128: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ad
--date=iso
Standard out: 
Standard error: warning: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied
fatal: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied
```

I ask this question in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794340/how-to-fix-the-error-fatal-unable-to-access-git-config-permission-denied?noredirect=1#comment109302694_61794340) but one person said that I should check the user and I see that I'm the user registered there. I think I need to go to git folder and allow permission in properties but I don't know to get into git folder in mac os

Comment: `sudo`   . This is God level option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .config folder is supposed to be owned by the user. It appears that the ownership got changed to system by mistake on your machine.

With following command, you can *restore* the *default permission* on your MacOS:

```
sudo chown -R <username> .config
```

(Substitute `<username>` with your username. You can find your username as follows: `whoami`)

When prompted for a password, enter *your* login password.

Comment: I did what you said but it still displays the same error and is it ok if my username in whoami is different in the git config --global -l username that I use. I run your code and input password and after that, I run flutter doctor but it displays the same error

Comment: no it says no such file or directory when I use cd .git

Comment: i cant cd in usr/bin/git

Comment: and if you don't access the .git folder, you must enter the same command above in the answer for the `.git` folder and not for the config folder (I misunderstand your question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213900/discussion-between-ken-verganio-and-swisscodemen).

Comment: when i cd the usr/bin/git it says no such file or directory

Comment: i found where my git folder is and when I run your code sudo chown -R <mysusername> .config it says no such file or directory and when I run the ls -la I don't see my username and also I don't see any .config file in my git folder

Comment: its in usr/local/git and when I run git init it says permission denied

Comment: I locate my .git folder but it says "zsh: permission denied: /Users/me/.git" thats why i can't run your ocde

Comment: but how do i access this .git folder

Comment: also the .git folder has zero bytes when i locate and open it it's empty

Comment: i ask another question in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61830920/where-to-find-the-config-directory-of-git-on-mac-os

Comment: i solved the problem by running sudo chown -R <username> .config or .git  in flutter folder