# where to find the .config directory of git on mac os?

Tags: git, permissions, config

I have this problem which is I need to restore the default permission on my git because when I'm executing the flutter doctor I get an error

```
fee@Mac-mini ~ % flutter doctor -v
warning: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied
fatal: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied
Failed to find the latest git commit date: VersionCheckError: Command 
exited
with code 128: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 -- 
pretty=format:%ad
--date=iso
Standard out: 
Standard error: warning: unable to access '.git/config': Permission 
denied
fatal: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied

Returning 1970-01-01 08:00:00.000 instead.
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, 0.0.0-unknown, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 
19D76, 
locale
    en-US)
    • Flutter version 0.0.0-unknown at /Users/fee/Documents/flutter
    • Framework revision  (), 1970-01-01 08:00:00.000
    • Engine revision b59e3e9c39
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-8.0.dev 2bf3259005)


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK.    
version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/fee/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.4.1, Build version 11E503a
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google 
 Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 
81.0.4044.138

    • No issues found!
fee@Mac-mini ~ %
```

I have a good friend who helps me in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61811373/how-to-allow-the-access-of-git-config-in-mac-os/61812401?noredirect=1#comment109346572_61812401) he said that if my run sudo chown -R  .config in .git directory it restores the default permission

but when i locate my .git folder in terminal it says permission denied that's why i cant run the code in .git folder to restore my user permission

```
fee@Mac-mini git % /Users/fee/.git         
zsh: permission denied: /Users/fee/.git
```

help me on how to access this .git folder that contains the .config to restore my permission or how to restore the default user permission using git config

Comment: Please edit your question to show the full command you're running and error output you're seeing as a code block.  Without seeing that, we can't help.

Comment: i edit my question @bk2204

Answer (score 0):

Copy the contents to a file and paste in as new file.

By that I mean open `.git/config` with a text editor, copy the stuff in there, then paste to a temporary file. Now delete the culprit config file and copy new config file to the `.git` folder